# Reallocating char array (string) by chunks in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, realloc

If I use chunks to reallocate memory for, let's say, every ten characters I read from console with getchar() function in C, and count every new char (position) with counter++, when I'm done with the word I'm on, if I add '\0' to last position in array (marked by counter), will I get rid of excess allocated space?

For example, if I want input to be names and lastnames of people (new line represents new string in an array of strings I'm working on):
Anna Johnson
Mark Twen
Gabe Michaelson

"Mark Twen" is 9 chars, and I add one more for the end of string, I've used up all 10 locations from allocated chunk. But "Gabe Michaelson" is 15 chars, if I add '\0'at 16th (counting from 1; or 15th, counting from 0), would I be wasting (leaking???) memory represented by 4 remaining unused locations, or would every string in an array of strings have it's own length without any leakage/using more memory then needed?

Comment: If you only allocate storage for the exact number of characters needed -- there is no wasted space. You do that by allocating pointers and then allocating storage (a separate block of memory) for each name ( `strlen(name) + 1` characters) you need to store. You then assign the beginning address for each allocated block storing names to each of your pointers in turn. (when you need more pointers, you simply `realloc` pointers and keep going)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, adding the `\0` doesn't deallocate space or affect the rest of the memory in any way.  Indeed, if you should later want to add more characters to the string, you can do so, up to the amount of space allocated.

If you really want to free up the memory at the end, the only way is to `realloc` it to a smaller size.  However, for a few bytes, that probably won't help very much, since `malloc` is unlikely to be able to make any use of a block that small, especially given that there are typically many bytes of overhead for each block.   So if your chunk size is relatively small, it is probably best just to leave it alone, and accept that a few bytes will be wasted - it should be insignificant in most cases.

It's not really a leak, since when you eventually `free()` the "Gabe Michaelson" string, the unused bytes at the end will be freed too.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me what happens with the remaining bytes, I now know I could try to further upgrade my solution by reallocating it to a smaller size using information gathered from counter.